# ¿Como enviar un archivo xml desde javaScript a un servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

tengo un problema lo que pasa es que estoy creando una función en una pagina web para que alguien pueda cargar un archivo xml y con base a las etiquetas de ese archivo xml, los inputs se van a llenar, ese es el objetivo, pero el problema que tengo es que al yo enviar mi formulario donde contiene mi archivo xml, el servlet lo detecta como que le pase un archivo null. Soy algo nuevo en esto, quisiera saber donde estoy mal, si bien no esta completo porque primero me gustaria ver que llegara bien el archivo para empezar a manejar las etiquetas y regresar un objeto json para empezar a llenar los inputs, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Este es la parte del html

```
<div>
  <form id="formCargarXML" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="archivoXML" accept=".xml">
     <button type="button" id="botonCargarXML">Cargar XML </button>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Asi lo tengo en JavaScript

```
    eventoCargarXML(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Se va a enviar el archivo XML");
    const form = document.getElementById("formCargarXML");
    const inputArchivo = form.querySelector('input[name="archivoXML"]');
    const archivoSeleccionado = inputArchivo.files[0];

    if (!archivoSeleccionado) {
        alert("Por favor, seleccione un archivo XML.");
        return;
    }
    
    if (!archivoSeleccionado.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")) {
    alert("El archivo seleccionado no es un archivo XML válido.");
    return;
}


    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("archivoXML", archivoSeleccionado);
    formData.append("archivoXML", archivoSeleccionado);
    console.log("Se imprime archivoSeleccionado");
    console.log(archivoSeleccionado);
    console.log("Se imprime formData");
    console.log(formData);
    // Recorre las entradas de formData y muestra su contenido
    for (const entry of formData.entries()) {
        console.log("Nombre de entrada:", entry[0]);
        console.log("Valor de entrada:", entry[1]);
    }

     fetch('/FuelsoftWEB/cargarXML', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' // Configura el tipo de medio como XML
    }
    })
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
    .then(datos => {
        console.log("esto fue lo que se devolvio");
        console.log(datos);
        //aqui va la funcion que llenara los inputs this.funcionLlenarInputs(datos);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al cargar el archivo XML:', error);
    });
}
```

Y esto es el codigo del servlet

```
 @RestController
public class CargarXMLServlet {
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/cargarXML", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = "application/json")
    public String cargarXML(@RequestBody MultipartFile archivoXML) {
        System.out.println(archivoXML);
        String respuesta = "";
        
        try {
            if (!archivoXML.isEmpty()) {
            // Aquí puedes imprimir el contenido del archivo o hacer otra operación para verificarlo
            System.out.println("Nombre del archivo: " + archivoXML.getOriginalFilename());
            System.out.println("Tipo de contenido: " + archivoXML.getContentType());
        } else {
            // Manejar el caso en el que no se haya seleccionado ningún archivo
            return "No se seleccionó ningún archivo.";
        }
//            
            Gson gson = new Gson();            
            CargarXMLDAO archivo = new CargarXMLDAO();
            RecDocumentosVO datosXML = archivo.obtenerDatos(archivoXML);
            
//            ArrayList<ProveedorPemexVO> proveedoresPemexVO = proveedoresDAO.provPemex();

            respuesta = gson.toJson(datosXML);
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CargarXMLServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        return respuesta;
    }
    
}
```